# Creating Tables and insert data to MariaDB Docker container directly after install

Tags: sql, docker, mariadb

I have a MariaDB Docker container which needs to be reinstalled sometimes during development. Is there a way to create my tables and insert my data after a `docker compose up` when everything is pruned before?

Comment: A check of [the MariaDB Docker docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) shows a section titled "Initializing a fresh instance", which describes using `entrypoint` to specify SQL dumps to create, populate, etc new DBs on build, which sounds like what you are looking for.  A quick search here on SO for "*mysql docker create tables*" turns up lots of answers suggesting the same.

Comment: You should be able to re-run your application's database migrations and seed-data jobs.  How would you normally load this data, without Docker involved?

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks. This answers my questions!